# How to set a breakpoint when debugging a compiled executable when source is located on source server

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, source-server

**Hi erveryone,**

**My Question is:**

How do I set a breakpoint, when debugging a binary executable in Visual Studio 2017 where I don't have any sources on my local machine?

**The Setup:**

- Win 10 PC with Visual Studio 2017 installed
- git as source repository in the local network
- TeamCity as Build Server also in the same local network
- TemaCity is setup as symbol and source server in Visual Studio

**The Process:**

1. Code gets written on the local machine and commited into the git repository
2. TeamCity Builds new binaries because of the commit
3. TemaCity also indexes the symbol and source files

**The Problem:**

Now I want to debug a specific binary build to see what went wrong.
I Load the Binary into Visual Studio and run it in Debug Mode and when there is an unhandelt exception and the application crashed, Visual Studio downloads the symbol file and the source file from TeamCity and displays the correct location where the exception happened.
So the that works as expected.

**But back to the question...** How do I set a Breakpoint when I want to investigate what the binary is doing if it not crashes?

In the example above Visual Studio downloads only one single source file from the source server (the one in which the exception was thrown).
Is there a way to browse the compelte source of this specific build in Visual Studio to set a breakpoint?

Comment: In don't understand your question, you have the source code and the pdb file, simply attach to the process and put a breakpoint and that's it, where is the problem?

Comment: I don't think you can do this without copying the source to your own machine/debug from the server. If you download the source from teamcity you should be able to debug fine. You can't really debug release versions, breakpoints won't be hit. So make sure you are debugging a debug version of the application. You can use the remote debugger (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging?view=vs-2017) - install it on your server, you can then attach to the running application in Visual Studio.

Comment: Remote debugging?

Comment: @Siraf attach to a process is only possible when the process is running. If the application is finnishing to fast, if not immediately if some conditions are not met, I will have no chance to attach.

Comment: @T.S. local debugging

Comment: @fstam Debuging a release version should be no problem, I have the pdb symbol files. But if I'm not able to get the source from the source server...then I'm starting to wonder what is the point of having a source index server at all...

Comment: Why don't you call the debugger from code in combination with a special command line parameter or an unofficial registry key, check this

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debugger.break?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @soulflyman Having the pdb's isn't always enough. In debug builds all kinds of memory guards end up in the binary whereas a release build gets optimized and might not break because it has nothing to break on..

Answer (score 1):

Call the debugger from your code with:

> `Debugger.Launch();`

Just put this statement at the position where you want your code to break.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch?view=netframework-4.7.2